# Never decreasing cumulative figure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`UniqueID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Date` date,
`Entry` VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (`UniqueID`)
);

INSERT INTO `test` (Date,Entry) VALUES 
('2015-09-01','text1'),
('2015-09-01','text1'),
('2015-09-01','text1'),
('2015-09-02','text2'),
('2015-09-02','text2'),
('2015-09-02','text2'),
('2015-09-02','text2'),
('2015-09-03','text3'),
('2015-09-03','text3'),
('2015-09-03','text3'),
('2015-09-04','text4'),
('2015-09-04','text4'),
('2015-09-04','text4'),
('2015-09-04','text4'),
('2015-09-04','text4'),
('2015-09-04','text4');

SET @total:= 0;
SET @prevCount:= 0;
SELECT 
    @total:=        IF (@prevCount <= COUNT(Entry),@total + (COUNT(Entry) - @prevCount),@total) AS total,
    @prevCount      := COUNT(Entry) AS dayTotal,    
    `Entry`,    
    `Date`
FROM test
GROUP BY `Date`
ORDER BY `Date` ASC

| total | dayTotal | Entry |                        Date |
|-------|----------|-------|-----------------------------|
|     3 |        3 | text1 | September, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|     4 |        4 | text2 | September, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
|     3 |        3 | text3 | September, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
|     6 |        6 | text4 | September, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
```

fiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9031/2

I need the total figure to never decrease because it is a cumulative figure over time.

My problem seems to be that MySQL doesn't store @prevCount on the loop - so I can't use it to calculate the total.

What I expect to see is that total will show

1. 3
2. 4
3. 4
4. 7

Note that the 7 is correct because it is the 4 plus the 3 new entries on the 4th.

Comment: Can you not just do a self join to get the counts, rather than using user variables?

Comment: Problem is my full table will have millions of rows so ideally I'd prefer not too.

Comment: A sequentuial count through the records will need to go through those millions of rows individually.

Comment: What is the count meant to be  count of? Is it the highest number of entries for any date up to that date?

Comment: According to [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html): 
"For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:

`SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;`

**However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined**

Comment: Thanks for that @Kenney - I wonder if there is a way to define the order of expressions!!

Comment: @Kickstart - my mistake I will be storing millions but looking over a few hundred at a time. Maybe that is a better option?

Comment: Please specify what you want the code to actually do.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.  For instance, you have `entry` in the sub select but not in the `group by`.

Comment: I've had a similar problem, and ended up calculating the cumulative in the application logic (it had to iterate over the result to generate HTML table rows anyway).

Comment: I have updated my question with expected results. Apologies if it wasn't initially clear.

Answer (score 0):

Doing calculations with variables is tricky.  With `group by`, you need to use a subquery.

Your logic doesn't make full sense to me.  The closest reasonable thing I can think of is a cumulative max:

```
SELECT @max := if(@max > dayTotal, @max, dayTotal)
FROM (SELECT `Date`, COUNT(*) as dayTotal
      FROM test
      GROUP BY `Date`
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @max := 0) params
ORDER BY `Date` ASC;
```

Note:  I removed `Entry` because it is not in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have now updated my question to show the expected results. Unfortunately the max isn't correct because it should increase by 3 on the last day.