# Mysql variables not totalling

Tags: mysql

I have created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b8805/1 which is also:

```
CREATE TABLE `simple_summary` (
  `RowCount` bigint(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dayTotal` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Entry` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `RowCount` (`RowCount`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `simple_summary`(`RowCount`,`dayTotal`,`Entry`,`Date`) values(1,3,'text1','2015-09-01'),(2,4,'text2','2015-09-02'),(3,3,'text3','2015-09-03'),(4,6,'text4','2015-09-04'),(0,0,'','0000-00-00');

SET @total = 0;
SELECT
    s1.rowCount,
    CASE
        WHEN s1.dayTotal <= s2.dayTotal     THEN @total:= @total
        WHEN s1.dayTotal > s2.dayTotal      THEN @total:= @total + (s1.dayTotal - s2.dayTotal)
    END     AS res,
/* I've also tried (but it fails */
@total:= @total + IF (s1.dayTotal <= s2.dayTotal,0,s1.dayTotal - s2.dayTotal),
    s1.dayTotal,
    s2.dayTotal
FROM simple_summary s1
JOIN simple_summary s2 ON s2.RowCount = s1.RowCount - 1
ORDER BY s1.RowCount ASC
```

This is on the back of another question [Never decreasing cumulative figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612797). From that question I have now created a table with intermediate results so I can then do additional calculations. I would expect the following results:

```
rowCount,res,dayTotal,dayTotal
1,3,3,0
2,4,4,3
3,4,3,4
4,7,6,3
```

For some reason I cannot set @total properly. Why on earth not? Because based on a comment in the above question I accept the order of variables - however there is now only 1 variable being used/set so order should play no part.

Comment: For reference I've managed to get this working as a derived table but it seems ridiculous that I can't do it without!